# Two-parameter template ambiguous binary operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, ambiguous

So I have a matrix class (of type Derived) based on CRTP that takes two template parameters `template<class T, class Derived>`, and need to overload the binary operators `+`, `-` and `*` for a matrix multiplied by a scalar (of class T). For the `*` operator it will for instance be

```
template <class T, class Derived>
Derived operator*(const Derived &other, const T scalar)
{
    Derived result = other;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < other.get_rows(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < other.get_cols(); j++)
        {
            result(i, j) *= scalar;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T, class Derived>
Derived operator*(const T scalar, const Derived &other) { return other * scalar; }
```

And then for example with `a * A`, where `a` is a double scalar and `A` a matrix object (dynamic), the compiler will not understand which operator to use, regardless of the class types, because of ambiguity in which template (`T` or `Derived`) to use.

*Anyone have a solution here?* Do I need to overload for specific template parameters such as `double`, `int` etc..?

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question. What `T`s can you multiply to a matrix object? What combination of types are allowed which arent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can't possibly discern two overloads, that take arbitrary types for *both* parameters. In

```
template <class T, class Derived>
Derived operator*(const Derived &other, const T scalar)  {...}
```

`Derived` and `T` are just template parameters that could be replaced by *any* type. The same goes for the other operator. Both declare a `operator*` that works for any two types.

If the matrix is of type `Derived` (i.e. you have `class Derived { ... };` somewhere) you probably meant to use this type instead of having a template parameter with the same name.

```
template <class T>
Derived operator*(const Derived &other, const T scalar) {...}

template <class T, class Derived>
Derived operator*(const T scalar, const Derived &other) {...}
```

Now you have two operators that take an instance of `Derived` as lhs and any other type as rhs or vice versa.

In addition you could limit the type of `T` with [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) or [C++ 20 concepts & constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) using [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) or [`std::is_floating_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) templates to allow only multiplication for `T`'s that are numbers.

---

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to use runtime polymorphism for different subclasses of matrices, you could keep your initial approach (with two template parameters) but limit the types that are allowed for `Dervied` the above mentioned methos, using [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). SFINAE should pick the correct overload then.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The challenge is that Derived can be e.g. a dynamic matrix, a fixed size matrix, etc.., and I would like to unify the binary operators, preventing me to implement one for the dynamic matrix, one for the static matrix, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yep, the link covers both, concepts and constraints. Edited the link text to reflect this.

Comment: @A_Man You can use runtime polymorphism or alternatively use your apporach and limit the types allowed for `Dervied`, see my latest edit.